# A question in a theorem of section 6.6 of Hoffman Kunze

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

I am reading Linear Algebra from Hoffman Kunze by myself and I have a question in a theorem of Section-" Invariant Direct Sums " :

[image]

> I am confused by how authors prove uniqueness of expression of $\alpha$ in proving that direct sum representation exists as for proving that direct sum representation exists I must show that representation of $\alpha$ is unique?

I got confused as I think author should take two representations and then prove them both be equal but here author only took $E_{i} \beta_{i} $ = $\alpha_{i} $ .

Can kindly tell how exactly author proved uniqueness( ie how last 6 lines of image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They did. They first established that
$$\alpha = E_1\alpha + \cdots + E_n\alpha$$
is one desired decomposition with $E_i\alpha \in W_i$.

Then they took a different decomposition
$$\alpha = \alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n$$
with $\alpha_i \in W_i$ and showed that actually it must be $\alpha_i = E_i\alpha$ for $1 \le i \le n$.

Therefore the decomposition $\alpha = E_1\alpha + \cdots + E_n\alpha$ is unique. For any other decomposition $$\alpha = \beta_1 + \cdots + \beta_n$$
with $\beta_i \in W_i$ we would also get $\beta_i = E_i\alpha$ and hence $\beta_i = \alpha_i$ for all $1 \le i \le n$.